# RAD telerik control customization

Tags: asp.net

I have loaded the telerik editor control on the Asp.net. But there are few properties which I  don't need  like image manager,image map editor, flash manager, media manager, document manager, and so on. how can i remove all these buttons and customize accodrding to my need. Any Idea.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Telerik [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editortoolbars/defaultcs.aspx) that explains how to pick toolbar buttons.

Comment: I tried to delete in TOOLSfile.xml. But it not editable. in demo  they just used the need tools in xml . can we edit toolsfile.xml

Comment: You can put it directly in your ASPX.  Read the documentation.

Comment: do you mean this way.                                             <rad:RadEditor ID="editor1" Runat="server">
    <Tools>
<telerik:EditorToolGroup >
<telerik:EditorTool Name="Cut" />
<telerik:EditorTool Name="Copy" />
<telerik:EditorTool Name="Paste" />
</telerik:EditorToolGroup>

</rad:RadEditor> but still I'm getting all the buttons. I have radcontrol folder in my application. do i need to delete it. If I delete it say it can't find the tools file.xml

Comment: That means you specified `ToolsFile="..."`.

Comment: I din't  get your point sorry. can you please explain more detailed.

Comment: Ok I got you point. I deleted the reference to toolfile And added in aspx page.

Comment: Ok I got you point. I deleted the reference to toolfile And added in aspx page. <rad:RadEditor ID="editor1" Runat="server" ToolsFile="~/Editor/Examples/ToolbarMode/ToolsFile.xml">. but as you said i tried to  add direct <telerik: editortool> (but it say not supported)